# encrypt a file while downloading from firebase storage?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a video file on firebase storage, I want to download the file and encrypt it at the same time. Now to do that I must have control over the bytes downloaded. What method of firebase storage downloads should I use to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypt it at the same time"?  What's the real requirement here? What do you need to accomplish?

Comment: @DougStevenson if we want to encrypt a video we need access to the bytes downloaded to encrypt them before saving to file. How do we access the coming bytes from firebase storage?

Comment: @DougStevenson is there a download method that give the file as bytes. I mean bytes after bytes?

Comment: @svkaka the file is manually uploaded on firebase storage not from device. It is not encrypted? Do you think I can let users download it first then encrypt it on client?

Comment: @svkaka to encrypt it I need a key, how to encrypt it or where?

Comment: @svkaka you are the most helpful right now, just one question shouldn't the key that I encrypt with be found on device to decrypt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method in Firebase Storage the can help you encrypt a file while downloading. You should do it yourself by creating/using a encryption system that can encrypt your files.

Comment: i know that but I mean I want to know what method would help access the coming bytes to encrypt them?

Comment: alex do you know any method in firebase storage api that helps accessing the coming bytes?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't one.

Comment: Then what should I do? Download the file on device then encrypt it on device?

Comment: Here is the [StorageReference class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference). Maybe `getBytes()` or `getStream()` can help you, otherwise encrypt it on client.

Comment: alex svkaka commented that I can encrypt file on storage before upload with firebase functions, what do you think of this?

Comment: but any way your answer should be accepted because it answers the above question.